# PL/SQL Result different than direct query

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

I've created PL/SQL procedure to update school register rank. 
It's look like that:

```
DECLARE
    studentsNumber NUMBER :=0;
    vSREDNIA RANK.SREDNIA%TYPE;
    vFIZYKA RANK.SREDNIA_FIZ%TYPE;
    vMATEMATYKA RANK.SREDNIA_MAT%TYPE;
    vPO RANK.SREDNIA_PO%TYPE;
    vWF RANK.SREDNIA_WF%TYPE;
    vREL RANK.SREDNIA_REL%TYPE;
    vMUZYKA RANK.SREDNIA_MUZ%TYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO studentsNumber FROM uczniowie;
    FOR id IN 1..studentsNumber LOOP

        SELECT SUM(WAGA * WYNIK)/SUM(WAGA) INTO vSREDNIA FROM OCENY
        WHERE WLASCICIEL = id;

        SELECT SUM(WAGA * WYNIK)/SUM(WAGA) INTO vFIZYKA FROM OCENY
        WHERE WLASCICIEL = id AND PRZEDMIOT = 'Fizyka';

        SELECT SUM(WAGA * WYNIK)/SUM(WAGA) INTO vMATEMATYKA FROM OCENY
        WHERE WLASCICIEL = id AND PRZEDMIOT = 'Matematyka';

        SELECT SUM(WAGA * WYNIK)/SUM(WAGA) INTO vPO FROM OCENY
        WHERE WLASCICIEL = id AND PRZEDMIOT = 'Przysposobienie Obronne';

        SELECT SUM(WAGA * WYNIK)/SUM(WAGA) INTO vWF FROM OCENY
        WHERE WLASCICIEL = id AND PRZEDMIOT = 'WF';

        SELECT SUM(WAGA * WYNIK)/SUM(WAGA) INTO vREL FROM OCENY
        WHERE WLASCICIEL = id AND PRZEDMIOT = 'Religioznastwo';

        SELECT SUM(WAGA * WYNIK)/SUM(WAGA) INTO vMUZYKA FROM OCENY
        WHERE WLASCICIEL = id AND PRZEDMIOT = 'Muzyka';

        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ID:' || id || ' Srednia: '|| vSREDNIA);

        UPDATE RANK
        SET SREDNIA = vSREDNIA, SREDNIA_MAT = vMATEMATYKA, SREDNIA_FIZ = vFIZYKA,
         SREDNIA_REL = vREL, SREDNIA_MUZ = vMUZYKA, SREDNIA_PO = vPO, SREDNIA_WF = vWF
        WHERE ID_UCZNIA = id;

    END LOOP;
    COMMIT;
END;
```

But columns SREDNIA and SREDNIA_WF are always 4 and other columns are empty. When I type in console for example:

```
        SELECT SUM(WAGA * WYNIK)/SUM(WAGA) FROM OCENY
        WHERE WLASCICIEL = 3;
```

I got appropriate result: 3,73913043.
Where does that difference come from? It's Oracle database if that is meaningful. DBMS_OUTPUT produces 1,2,3... IDs, so it's ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to checking that your rank table columns have the correct number precision, your code is not going to be reliable.

Not only are you doing row-by-row (aka slow-by-slow) processing, you're potentially not going to get all the correct student ids. That "count the number of students and then assume all the ids start from 1 and are consecutive" step that you make do do the loop might not actually be correct. What if the lowest student id is 2? And what if there are gaps in the student numbering? You're going to end up doing unnecessary work for some ids and miss out others entirely. At the very least, you should convert that into a cursor for loop, in order to make sure you select all the ids from the uczniowie table.

Also, all those individual selects could be done in one single select. And whilst you're at it, you could then incorporate it into a single update/merge statement. thus negating the need for all the looping in the first place, something like (untested, since you didn't provide any sample data):

```
merge into rank tgt
using (select wlasciciel student_id,
              sum(waga * wynik)/sum(waga) vsrednia,
              sum(case when przedmiot = 'Fizyka' then waga * wynik end)/sum(case when przedmiot = 'Fizyka' then waga end) vfizyka,
              sum(case when przedmiot = 'Matematyka' then waga * wynik end)/sum(case when przedmiot = 'Matematyka' then waga end) vmatematyka,
              sum(case when przedmiot = 'Przysposobienie Obronne' then waga * wynik end)/sum(case when przedmiot = 'Przysposobienie Obronne' then waga end) vpo,
              sum(case when przedmiot = 'WF' then waga * wynik end)/sum(case when przedmiot = 'WF' then waga end) vwf,
              sum(case when przedmiot = 'Religioznastwo' then waga * wynik end)/sum(case when przedmiot = 'Religioznastwo' then waga end) vrel,
              sum(case when przedmiot = 'Muzyka' then waga * wynik end)/sum(case when przedmiot = 'Muzyka' then waga end) vmuzyka
       from   oceny
       group by wlasciciel) src
  on (tgt.id_ucznia = src.student_id)
when matched then
  update set tgt.srednia = src.vsrednia,
             tgt.srednia_mat = src.vmatematyka,
             tgt.srednia_fiz = src.vfizyka,
             tgt.srednia_rel = src.vrel,
             tgt.srednia_muz = src.vmuzyka,
             tgt.srednia_po = src.vpo,
             tgt.srednia_wf = src.vwf
when not matched then -- optional insert clause, just in case the id isn't already present in the rank table
  insert (tgt.id_ucznia,
          tgt.srednia,
          tgt.srednia_mat,
          tgt.srednia_fiz,
          tgt.srednia_rel,
          tgt.srednia_muz,
          tgt.srednia_po,
          tgt.srednia_wf)
  values (src.student_id,
          src.vsrednia,
          src.vmatematyka,
          src.vfizyka,
          src.vrel,
          src.vmuzyka,
          src.vpo,
          src.vwf);
```

You'll find that single statement will outperform your procedure (1. you're not having to query the same table 7 times for every single id and 2. you're not having to switch contexts between pl/sql and sql every time you move to another id). It also should be easier to debug, because now you can run the single select statement on its own to see the output and check whether it matches with what you're expecting.

Answer (score 1):

See, for example

```
SQL> create table tmp$i (i number(38, 0), j number(38, 2), k number(38, 4));

Table created

SQL> insert into tmp$i values (2.55, 2.55, 2.55);

1 row inserted

SQL> select * from tmp$i;

         I          J          K
---------- ---------- ----------
         3       2,55     2,5500
```

Check if your table fields described with appropriate scale.